# In Bluemix, from a Python Flask App with integrated Cloudant DB, how do I retrieve Cloudant data?

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a Python Flask app with integrated Cloudant running in Bluemix.
The Cloudant database consists of a few documents.
Each document has a "name" and an "email" field in addition to the default _id and rev field.

Using the CouchDB interface I can easily print out the addresses of the db field

`doc in db:
     docs +="<br>"+doc`

gives the following result:

> 71076864699bfbd07b0f1684945e01ef
>   _design/1e0c70cd2cad4211581be1c25adb1eea86d1b2f0
>   _design/3478963fd9207264b8ab48dbc23187ca9ad7204a

I now want to print out the actual values of the "name" and "email" fields.
I can do that in the Cloudant UI with a Query or with an Index.

How do I run this Query or Index from my Python app to show the actual values of the name and email fields? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make HTTP requests to the proper Cloudant endpoints using the credentials and URL for your Cloudant database that is provisioned for your application (found in the VCAP_SERVICES Environment Variable).

We have an [alpha-stage python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloudant/2.0.0a2), which we encourage you to use. It can do basic things at the moment and reduces the amount of boilerplate code you will need.

Comment: Thanx, that looks very interesting, I wasn't aware of it. At the moment, however, I am really interested in learning "the established way" as I described in my post. So it would be great if someone can provide a small example.

Comment: The "established way", if there is one, would be to use the Requests library. The cloudant library uses Requests under the hood and gives you access to the Requests.session object. So no difference. If the cloudant library doesn't provide some particular functionality you need, you can then use the Requests session object to make an HTTP request (see [here](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.org/en/53377-docs-via-sphinx/getting_started.html#end-point-access)).

You'll want to be familiar with https://docs.cloudant.com to understand all of the HTTP endpoints that are available.

Comment: Just want to put this out there... Our Python Cloudant library is now at a stable release.  Check it out [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cloudant).

Answer (score 0):

This detailed [Tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/tutorials/create_database.html#creating-and-populating-a-simple-cloudant-nosql-db-database-on-ibm-cloud) shows you how to do this.

You can also find the Cloudant Python Documentation [here](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html)